# UTC Time on Google App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, time

What's the best way to work out the time when my servlet in google app engine is hit ?

if I call System.currentTimeMillis() and store that info will it be reliable ?

I don't need milliseconds precision.

I just want to store an entity with the date on when it arrives.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't be reliable.

In Dan Sanderson's book, "Programming Google App Engine" he says:

> It's worth noting that App Engine makes no guarantees that the system 
>   clocks of all of its web servers are synchronized. <...> The server clock 
>   is not consistent enough as a source of time data for a real-world application, 
>   but it's good enough for this example.

http://books.google.com/books?id=6cL_kCZ4NJ4C&lpg=PA25&dq=clocks%20synchronized%20google%20app%20engine&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=clocks%20synchronized%20google%20app%20engine&f=false

Comment: Nick Johnson says that the clocks are synced. So I don't know if this is right.

Comment: let's assume he is not. what would it be a possible solution ?

Comment: In Python, you could use a DateTimeProperty on your model with auto_now_add=True.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#DateTimeProperty

I'm guessing there is a Java equivalent, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

> if I call System.currentTimeMillis()
>   and store that info will it be
>   reliable ?

Yes.

Comment: thanks Nick. 
How do you know ? empirical evidence ? found this somewhere in some google docs  ?

Comment: Well, it's the system time. It's reliable and accurate, because the servers are kept in sync.