# App Engine Tasks with ETA are fired much later than scheduled

Tags: google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I am using Google App Engine Task push queues to schedule future tasks that i'd like to occur within second precision of their scheduled time.

Typically I would schedule a task 30 seconds from now, that would trigger a change of state in my system, and finally schedule another future task.

Everything works fine on my local development server.

However, now that I have deployed to the GAE servers, I notice that the scheduled tasks run late. I've seen them running even two minutes after they have been scheduled.

From the task queues admin console, it actually says for the ETA:

```
ETA: "2013/11/02 22:25:14 0:01:38 ago" 
Creation Time: "2013/11/02 22:24:44 0:02:08 ago"
```

Why would this be?

I could not find any documentation about the expectation and precision of tasks scheduled by ETA.

I'm programming in python, but I doubt this makes any difference.\

In the python code, the eta parameter is documented as follows:

```
eta: A datetime.datetime specifying the absolute time at which the task
        should be executed. Must not be specified if 'countdown' is specified.
        This may be timezone-aware or timezone-naive. If None, defaults to now.
```

My queue Settings:

```
queue:    
- name: mgmt
  rate: 30/s
```

The system is under no load what so ever, except for 5 tasks that should run every 30 seconds or so.

UPDATE:

I have found https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4901 which is an accepted feature request for timely queues although nothing seems to have been done about it. It accepts the fact that tasks with ETA can run late even by many minutes.

What other alternative mechanisms could I use to schedule a trigger with second-precision?

Comment: As far as I understand it an ETA Is a guide and can't be relied on.

Comment: The docs say `A datetime.datetime object which provides the earliest time when this task will execute.` and I always read this as not earlier than the ETA but could be a bit later

Comment: I understand the "no earlier than" policy. However I would have thought that the request is triggered within a few seconds at worst, and then it is up to the app owner to have it serviced. I wonder if there is any guarantee that the task request is fired within a certain amount of time.

Comment: Hey what is your queue rate, bucket size etc. Post and reply. I use timed taskes with ETA and work precicely.

Comment: Hi @JimmyKane, thanks. I added the details of the queue. And a reference to a gae feature request that accepts that tasks can be run many minutes late. I'd be interested to know how you get it working precisely and how precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the issue to the GAE team and I got the following response:

```
This appears to be an isolation issue. Short version: a high-traffic user is sharing underlying resources and crowding you out. 

Not a very satisfying response, I know. I've corrected this instance, but these things tend to revert over time. 

We have a project in the pipeline that will correct the underlying issue. Deployment is expected in January or February of 2014.
```

See https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10228

See also thread: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4901

After they "*corrected this instance*" I did some testing for a few hours. The situation improved a little especially for tasks without ETA. But for tasks with ETA I still see at least half of them running at least 10 seconds late. This is far from reliable for my requirements

For now I decided to use my own scheduling service on a different host, until the GAE team "*correct the underlying issue*" and have a more predictable task scheduling system.

Answer (score 1):

GAE makes no guarantees about clock synchronization within and across their data centers; see [UTC Time on Google App engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591882/utc-time-on-google-app-engine) for a related discussion.  So you can't even specify the absolute time accurately, even if they made the (different) guarantee that tasks are executed within some tolerance of the target time.

If you really need this kind of precision, you could consider setting up a persistent GAE "backend" instance that synchronizes itself with a trusted external clock, and provides task queuing and execution services.

(Aside: Unfortunately, that approach introduces a single point of failure, so to fix that you could just take the next steps and build a whole cluster of these backends...  But at that point you may as well look elsewhere than GAE, since you're moving away from the GAE "automatic transmission" model, toward AWS's "manual transmission" model.)

Comment: Thanks David. I wouldn't need to sync to an external clock as I can tolerate a second or two at max variation. The "backend" idea would be an option.  The single point of failure would not be the biggest issue either as I can have a cron monitoring that everything is still kicked off. The problem with a dedicated backend is that it is a little bit overkill in terms of cost and complication. I am currently considering having a chain of requests that sleep just enough (at most ~20s) and wake up when i'm ready to execute my logic. at the end it will re-task itself immediately.

Comment: I saw a post from a couple years ago where a member of the GAE/Python team stated that they use NTP for all GAE computers.  This is not an official guarantee, but it makes sense that they would do this and one can deduce a degree of time sync from that.